# Text in Bootstrap footer aligning to center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

The footer in my webpage is aligned to the center.

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="text-muted credit" style="color:#fff">xyz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This code works perfectly for other pages but for this particular page it doesn't work. This page contains a fullcalender UI that I have plugged but I doubt that has anything to do with my issue.

Comment: Tried that. It has nothing to do with the plugin.

Comment: It's the bootstrap 3.0 css.

Comment: ok i'm just hardcoding it for now but for some reason the text in the container is floating (or some other method) to the left in normal circumstances.. But in this case it isn't. I'll look at the plugin again

Comment: The code itself http://jsbin.com/UXEvIWI/1/edit is not centering. The stuff on the page before it probably doesn't have a clearfix on it or an unclosed div or some other element is not closed.

Comment: I've checked the page source many times through and all the elements are closed. For some reason the text is moving to the left in normal cases (or margin or padding is removed) and not in this case.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try adding the "text-center" class to the container. So you will end up with this:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container text-center">
    <p class="text-muted credit" style="color:#fff">xyz</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

See if that works. Otherwise, maybe paste your markup for the page so that we can look at it. It would also be helpful if you inspected the footer element with chrome for example and attached the screenshot of it.

Answer (score 11):

For me with Bootstrap 3 don't forget to specified col-md-12 col-sm-12 and col-xs-12 to work.

Other things avoid using `style="color:#fff"` it breaks color theme. Use `navbar-text` instead. So you should have something like this :

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default  navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div class="container text-center">
        <p class="navbar-text col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">&copy; xyz</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Last word, use `container` and not `container-fluid`

Comment: I thought and I read at many places that col-xs-12 gets applied by default for small screens. I am stuck with the same problem.

Comment: This is solve my day. Keep searching around and bang with `container` only!